# rtl when last word is english

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

I have rtl problem when the last word in label is english and then ( character. for example:

```css
label {
  direction: rtl;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<label>php (0 הצבעות)</label>
```

I get wrong direction of show.
need to be:
[click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxj2q.png)

but show:
[click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trkbY.png)

what can I do to solve this problem? it's happen only in chrome browser.

Edit:
fix it by add

```
&#x200F;
```

before (

thank you all.

Comment: In what browser?

Comment: right, only in chrome... @c-smile

Comment: In the future, you should add your fix as an answer rather than an addition to your previous post.

Answer (score 5):

use `unicode-bidi: bidi-override;`

```css
label {
   direction: rtl;
   unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<label>php (0 הצבעות)</label>
```

Comment: But now it's reverse the english letters :(

Comment: you can use like this:
`<style>
 label {
  direction:rtl;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
 }
</style>
<label> 
 <span dir="ltr">phps</span>
 <span dir="ltr">(0 הצבעות)</span>    
</label>`